# How do I theme view fields, with custom templates or overwriting the output from the UI?

Tags: views, theming

I am having some confusion in theming a view output in Drupal.

While theming a view with Fields, you can either create template files for every view like *views-view-unformatted--view-name--block-name.html.twig* or you can use the *Rewrite Results* option in the fields configuration as shown in the screenshot.

> [image: Drupal8-Views-Field-Configuration]

I want to know which is the best practice to follow and the reason for it.

Some of my points are the following.

- The rewrite output is stored in the database; accidental wipes of the database will be destructive.
- Creating template file will ensure that someone who is not familiar with Views will have no effect even if they accidentally altered the code.
- Keeping the code in rewrite result will give easy access to edits through Views UI.

In my case, the homepage of the theme I am trying to integrate have so many sections (with different HTML structure like Collage, Card, and List) which are based on specific taxonomy terms.

What are the pros and cons of both the methods? What should I follow?

Comment: You're missing quite a big point and that's the reusability of template files. You say `you can either create template files for every view` this isn't necessarily true you can have 1 template file that is used every time that field is used within all of your views. So that would save you having to do a rewrite on every occasion you use it or if you want to change that field in the future. Also another factor is the content with the rewrite will be filtered so certain html will get stripped whereas a template isn't. E.g. you want to add a data attribute to a field

Comment: Best practice is to display entities in a dedicated **view mode**. Like having Article nodes and add a new view mode for them. And when necessary use custom **field formatters** to customize the field output in this view mode. Then in a view display the Articles selecting the view mode you created earlier. **Templating or displaying single fields in Views should be avoided when possible**.

Comment: @leymannx Citation needed? That's not a (global) best practice I'm familiar with; it would mean you can't create tables for a start (or it would be very awkward to do that in a view mode at least)...

Comment: @Clive – Uh judging from your comment it seems "best practice" has a much stricter meaning. I thought it comes more down to "proven in reality" to keep the admin UX simple and the UI intact. Extensive usage of fine-grained templates and multiple Views fields in my experience can become a hell to maintain on the long run. I also thought that to use field formatters over templating would be a widely accepted consensus. I remember being pushed to highlight that templating most of the times isn't the optimal way when answering templating questions with templating solutions.

Comment: @Leigh Thanks for pointing that out. Yes, theming in Drupal can be component based and you can create a particular template for a specific field. I understand the point but I am sure that it won't work in my use case since a single field is used in different styles in my theme. That means it I may have to create multiple field templates (Mostly View Specific).

Comment: @leymannx Thanks for the suggestion. I haven't worked with View Modes yet. Definitely, I will check that out and let me check it will work for my use case.

Comment: @Clive So, what's your opinion? Using _Field Formatter_ is better than creating overriding view templates.

Comment: _Using Field Formatter is better than creating overriding view templates._ That's a very sweeping statement, I don't agree with it personally. That's why we don't usually address this type of question here, it's entirely subjective, and there isn't a right or wrong answer, just people's personal beliefs. But the comments of a vaguely related question aren't really the place to get into such a discussion :)

Comment: @leymannx "Best practice" (in my world) means you should always do x instead of y. I don't believe you can say that for the principles of templating views, situation provides too much nuance in my experience. But each to their own, that's why best practice questions don't do so well on QA sites - they're never objectively answerable

Comment: @Clive Actually I missed a **?** symbol in my previous comment. :D